# Can't connect to rpc.blockchain.info with bitcoin-cli

Tags: blockchain.info, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I'm trying to, given a bitcoin address, retrieve the last X transactions to this address. After researches, I found [this](https://www.blockchain.com/es/api/json_rpc_api) to be an interesting solution, as I don't want to download and validate the entire blockchain for this simple purpose.

On my Windows 10 machine, I downloaded bitcoin-core and tried to send a `getinfo` (I didn't execute bitcoin-qt as I don't want it to start syncing with the blockchain) :

```
./bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=rpc.blockchain.info -rpcport=80 -rpcuser=my_id -rpcpassword=my_password getinfo
```

I got an error message complaining about bitcoin.conf and credentials (indeed, there was no bitcoin.conf file in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Bitcoin\`)

So I created a bitcoin.conf file :

```
server=1
rpcuser=my_id
rpcpassword=my_password
rpcport=80
rpcconnect=rpc.blockchain.info
#rpcssl=1        #SSL mode for RPC is no longer supported
```

However, I get this error (bitcoin-cli has been allowed to access the web in Windows Firewall) :

```
error: couldn't connect to server: EOF reached (code 1)
(make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)
```

Has the service been discontinued ? Or is there a problem with my configuration ?

Comment: looks like you're not the only one having problems: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1761533.0

Comment: Oh, the topic has been created in january 2017..... I think they stopped providing this service, but didn't removed the doc webpage... Is there any alternative ? All I want is basically getting the result of ` listtransactions` and parse the result to get senders and transaction amount (in a C++ app if it matters). By the way, replacing .info with .com doesn't help either...

Comment: You mean like this? https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address

Comment: This is P-E-R-F-E-C-T ! And I don't need to install anything on my system... Thank you !

Comment: cool let's make an answer so people can find it more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this service is no longer available per [other discussions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1761533.0) (and a failed ping of `rpc.blockchain.info`).

An alternative would be to use the [address query](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api) on blockchain.info's api:

`https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address`

#### Example

**Single Address**

`https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1AJbsFZ64EpEfS5UAjAfcUG8pH8Jn3rn1F`

Address can be base58 or hash160

- Optional limit parameter to show n transactions e.g. &limit=50 (Default: 50, Max: 50)
- Optional offset parameter to skip the first n transactions e.g. &offset=100 (Page 2 for limit 50)

```
{
    "hash160":"660d4ef3a743e3e696ad990364e555c271ad504b",
    "address":"1AJbsFZ64EpEfS5UAjAfcUG8pH8Jn3rn1F",
    "n_tx":17,
    "n_unredeemed":2,
    "total_received":1031350000,
    "total_sent":931250000,
    "final_balance":100100000,
    "txs":[--Array of Transactions--]
}
```